# Assign custom methods in mongoose .d.ts so I can use them anywhere with mongoose in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, types

I am trying to create a custom function in mongoose Api hooks but the function is not defined as it has not declared. I have created index.d.ts separate file but don't know how to add that.

const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;

```
mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function (options:ICacheOptions = {}) {
  this.useCache = true;
  this.hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || "");
  return this;
}
```

link :: [cache.ts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HjivkBzDne9bNfp7O33CMo834nQxL9Ja/view?usp=sharing)!

error is: *Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'Query'. Did you mean 'catch'?*

what I have tried: I created .d.ts file and try to declare them.

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
  interface DocumentQuery<T,  DocType extends import("mongoose").Document, QueryHelpers = {}>{
    mongooseCollection: {
      name: any;
    };
    cache():DocumentQuery<T[], Document> & QueryHelpers;
    useCache: boolean;
    hashKey: string;

  }
}
```

link:: [index.d.ts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MmHWm3cZ2ryoeVgxoIQHqb_MD_oVwJqy/view?usp=sharing)!

My Errors are ::

```
src/lib/services/cache.ts(16,26): error TS2551: Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'Query<any>'. Did you mean 'catch'?
src/lib/services/cache.ts(17,8): error TS2339: Property 'useCache' does not exist on type 'Query<any>'.
src/lib/services/cache.ts(18,8): error TS2339: Property 'hashKey' does not exist on type 'Query<any>'.
src/lib/services/cache.ts(25,12): error TS2339: Property 'useCache' does not exist on type 'Query<any>'.
src/lib/services/cache.ts(30,41): error TS2339: Property 'mongooseCollection' does not exist on type 'Query<any>'.
src/lib/services/cache.ts(33,52): error TS2339: Property 'hashKey' does not exist on type 'Query<any>'.
src/lib/services/cache.ts(45,22): error TS2339: Property 'hashKey' does not exist on type 'Query<any>'.
src/lib/services/cache.ts(46,24): error TS2339: Property 'hashKey' does not exist on type 'Query<any>'.
```

I want somehow I can fix this and also want to know how can I extend some property in .d.ts if they are class. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your augmentation does work. It needs to be placed somewhere that you have configured TypeScript to look for source files. The `declare module` style of type definition is called an "ambient declaration" which means that you don't have to put it in any particular directory or file. It can even be in a regular `.ts` file. The easiest thing to do is to put the declaration in `cache.ts`, the same file where you assign `mongoose.Query.prototype.cache`.

Edit: I forgot to address your specific question about augmenting a class. As you guessed you can augment a class by using the `interface` keyword. That is because in TypeScript defining a class does two things: it defines a value (the constructor function that is invoked when you call, e.g., `new DocumentQuery`), and a type for instances of the class which is really an interface. The value and the type both have the same name. Because the type part of a class is an interface you can augment it like any other interface.

So in this case you augment the `DocumentQuery` type, which is the superclass of `Query`, but you assign the `cache` method to the `Query` prototype. That works because `Query` extends `DocumentQuery`, so when you declare that `DocumentQuery` now has a `cache` method TypeScript assumes that subclasses, including `Query`, have the same method. This does lead to a discrepancy: TypeScript now assumes that `DocumentQuery` instances have a `cache` method, but you only really defined that method for `Query`. It would be more accurate to either change your type declaration to augment `Query` instead of `DocumentQuery`, or to assign the method implementation to `DocumentQuery.prototype` instead of to `Query.prototype`.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks it worked like a charm. But when I added in the same cache.ts file. I wanted if it could work in .d.ts file. I use interface Query<T> extends DocumentQuery<T, any> { <my declaration> }.

Comment: @ShaileshJha It should work in a `.d.ts` file if you put the `.d.ts` file in the same directory with your source files. For example if your `tsconfig.json` file has the option `"include": ["src"]` then the `.d.ts` file would need to be in `src/` or in a subdirectory of `src`. You could put the file in a different directory if you add that directory to the list in the `"include"` setting.